# google script gmail addon add textarea inputText

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-addons

I have created a simple gmail add-on using google's app script. I would like to implement a **textarea** input. I have referred the documents, but I couldn't find the appropriate method.

[gmail add-on card service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/)

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 1):

You can call `setMultiline(true)` on TextInput which will render the input box as multiline. There is no explicit TextArea in Gmail addon UI as of now.

Comment: we can set multiline(true) but we need increase height of textinput,its look normal input filed

Comment: how can we increase the height of input fields with textarea?